# Problems with retrieving radio button value for feedback form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to build a simple feedback form. The user will answer a series of yes or no questions. If they choose no, then they will be provided with a comment form to include text.

Currently, I'm having problems with retrieving radio button values. I am trying to print them in the console, but nothing happens when I choose the appropriate choice. If the user chooses 'no', it needs to be able to remember the comment that will get submitted.

My JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/787x18vx/

**HTML**

```
<p>You are providing feedback</p>
<form>
  <div id="question-1">
    <label for="question-1">Is this correct?</label>
    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="choice-1" />Yes
    <input type="radio" value="no" name="choice-1" />No
  </div>
  <div id="question-2">
    <label for="question-2">Another question</label>
    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="choice-2" />Yes
    <input type="radio" value="no" name="choice-2" />No
  </div>
  <div id="question-3">
    <label for="question-3">One more question</label>
    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="choice-3" />Yes
    <input type="radio" value="no" name="choice-3" />No
  </div>
  <br />
  <button>Send Feedback</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var firstInput = 'input[name=choice]';
var firstInputValue = $('input[name=choice-1]:checked').val();
$(firstInput).on('click', function() {
  console.log(firstInputValue);
  console.log($('input[name="choice-1"]:checked').val());
  console.log($('input[name="choice-2"]:checked').val());
  // if value === 'no' show comment form
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/787x18vx/7/

Comment: @brettkc Thank you. I also like this solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `input[name=choice]` selector which is not exisiting.

Use `input[type=radio]` instead.

```
var firstInput = 'input[type=radio]';
var firstInputValue = $('input[name=choice-1]:checked').val();
$(firstInput).on('click', function() {
  console.log(firstInputValue);
  console.log($('input[name="choice-1"]:checked').val());
  console.log($('input[name="choice-2"]:checked').val());
  // if value === 'no' show comment form
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/787x18vx/6/)

Comment: Why is the first value `undefined` when it gets printed in console? Variable doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mapr Because you set the `firstInputValue` outside the on click event which at initial state the value is undefined.

Comment: @mapr I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/787x18vx/8/) where the `firstInputValue` is inside the onclick event function. Also this is just an answer to fix for retrieving values correctly, it doesn't show all the values for the three choices. It just show the values from 1st and second choices.

Comment: @mapr Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`var firstInput = 'input[name=choice]';`
This is looking for something specifically with the name `choice`, which doesn't appear to be in your html.

There are two quick ways about this.
First, just change your selector:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){...
```

This will trigger the function on a click of any radio

Another way is with the wildcard selector:

```
var firstInput = 'input[name^=choice]';
```

The `^` should make is so any input with the name starting with `choice` gets selected.

This method should work, but targeting `input[type=radio]` is probably a better solution,

Comment: Should I be using `onclick` or `onchange`? What if the user wants to go back and change things?

Comment: Either would work I would think. Change will fire on the initial click, then any click after that when the value wouldn't change. Click will fire every time regardless. It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the -1 in your name

```
var firstInput = 'input[name=choice-1]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is trying to get tags with name exactly equals 'choice'. You can search by prefix with the following

```
var firstInput = 'input[name|="choice"]';
```

This will get all tags which name starts with 'choice'